# Refresh error when sharing .pbix file with others

Tags: powerbi

I am running into an error after sharing my .pbix file with a colleague. The query runs perfectly for me, not returning a single error. However after sharing the file with a colleague; when they open this up in their PBI desktop and try to refresh the data, they get the following error: - [image]

Which says 'We cannot convert the value null to type Record.'

***I get no such error when refreshing the data***, **and the query (and parameters) are identical.** The data source is Airtable and the privacy level is set to none.

[image]

I have tried everything, even taking control of their screen, pasting the query in as new and it still does not work. We both have the most up to date version of PBI desktop, as well as the most up to date version of Windows (as this is controlled by our IT department).

The code which I have used for the query exists here:

https://github.com/Airtable-Labs/msft-power-query-m-language/blob/main/retrieve-all-records-from-table.m

Any suggestions are welcome to try and help troubleshoot this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get to the bottom of the issue.

Firstly, restart the device in use.

Re-Launch Power BI Desktop, navigate to:
**File -> Options and Settings -> Data source settings -> Edit Permissions** -> then change **Credentials Type** to ***Anonymous***.

This change must be TO ANONYMOUS, FROM WINDOWS or any other credential type.